# What design pattern(s) to use?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, func

I want to design an easily extensible item system for my game where I don't need to modify existing code much. I want to add items with new effects on the fly.

Traits my items have in common:

A name,
a description,
an npc sell price,
if it can be equipped,
required level,
if it is usable in battle,
if it is usable outside of battle,
a cooldown

So I can encapsulate this already into a class. But now there are item effects.

Example:
heals x health points,
heals x mana points,
removes debuff x,
adds buff x,
gives x stat points on equipping,
has x% chance to create some other effect when equipped,
etc.

And those can be combined like: heals x health and mana points. The first four are examples for effects a usable item can have while the last two are examples for effects equipable items can have.

The idea behind it is that I have this structure in a database as well and I can add a new item with a new effect combination in my database, my code reads this then and builds it together into a new fancy item, without me having to modify much. The only time I need to modify my code is when I add new effects obviously.

How would you put this together in design pattern(s)?

I thought of decorator. Is there a different, better design pattern for this or maybe even a combination of multiple design patterns?

Comment: The simplest way is to give an id to each effect, implement each of the effect (and duplicate code for combined effect). If there are many combinations and the combination can only be at most 2 effect at a time, you can use 2 ids. As for the OOP part, you can have a list of objects that implements Effect interface for each of the item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a decorator pattern is good for your needs. Think of a pizza with different tops. You can warp the basic pizza with many tops and at the end you call a function to sum the prize or whatever. It's a kind of wrapper and you pass the object to the next class. Hence you need only a basic class and can add new (top)-class when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to decorate your objects with additional functionality without modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, though I believe it needs more words than can fit into a comment:

Picking a design pattern for a chunk of code is not something which you would typically do up-front (If you do it this way, be prepared to change it after you've seen it working); it's something which you're more likely to do after you already have some working code in-place and are looking to refactor it.  - Chances are that whatever decisions you make now will be affected by many (currently) unknown factors once you've started writing code.

I'd suggest thinking more about the features, behaviour and functionality which you'd like to create, and then just begin writing code to see what works and further develop your ideas.   Trying to solve a problem by designing it up-front around buzzwords like "factory", "decorator", "visitor" etc most likely won't lead you to a solution - design is very much an iterative process of continual improvement, change and refinement.

As an aside, and specifically on OO design, have a careful think about the SOLID principles while you're writing code; they should help you make decisions when you come to refactoring

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SOLIDPrinciples.aspx

http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod